# if Phone Number is null or 0, then mobile number , if mobile number too is 0 or null , then 0 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Help me plz

I want to get  if Phone Number is null or 0, then select mobile number , if mobile number too is 0 or null , then select 0

```
DECLARE 
    @phoneNumber varchar(MAX),
    @nReservationID varchar(MAX)


SELECT 
    @phoneNumber = 
       (CASE 
             WHEN ISNULL(RDG.nPhoneNumber  ,'') IN ('0','-',NULL)  
             THEN ISNULL(RDG.nMobileNumber, '0')  
             WHEN ISNULL(RDG.nMobileNumber, '0')  IN ('0','-',NULL)  
             THEN '0' 
             ELSE ISNULL(rdg.nPhoneNumber  ,'0')  END)
FROM tblReservation_Details_Guest RDG 
WHERE RDG.nReservationID = @nReservationID
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you just want [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(RDG.nPhoneNumber,'0'),NULLIF(RDG.nMobileNumber,'0'),'0')
```

`COALESCE` returns the first non-NULL expression. `NULLIF` will return `NULL` if its two arguments match, otherwise it returns the first of its arguments.

So the `COALESCE`s first expression will be `NULL` if `RDG.nPhoneNumber` is either `NULL` or `'0'`. And its second expression will be `NULL` if `RDG.nMobileNumber` is either `NULL` or `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, nothing worked....but this was the answer I found out

```
DECLARE @phoneNumber VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 
@phoneNumber =

(CASE WHEN RDG.nPhoneNumber IN ('0','-',NULL)
THEN RDG.nMobileNumber
WHEN RDG.nMobileNumber IN('0','-',NULL)
THEN 
RDG.nPhoneNumber
ELSE '0'
END)
FROM tblReservation_Details_Guest RDG where RDG.nReservationID=783689



SELECT
@phoneNumber as 'Phone number'
```

Thanks for replying and showing effort :)